Not able to access strapi after deploying it to Lightsail. What could be the issue?
I've to deploy my strapi app on AWS lightsail, & for that I followed, https://strapi.io/blog/deploying-strapi-to-your-own-vps to create and run strapi.
When I'm accessing, the static IP is assigned. I'm getting Bitnami welcome page (Check SS).
And when I'm trying to access any of the below IPs, I'm getting error on chrom
This page isn’t working
[MY_IP_ADDRESS] didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

http://<public-ip>:1337/
http://<public-ip>:1337/admin


As per pm2 list server is runing. Only additional thing, I did was adding a firewall, by keeping in mind, http/https/1337/ssh ports are allowed.
Those configuration done after reading https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-debian#step-1-installing-ufw
But still, it did not work out. How do see the admin portal?
**EDIT - **
Tried - HTTP://[MY_IP]/admin


Since your using ufw, you don't need to set it up, inside the linux distro, you can manage the open ports in Lightsail Administration, for the instance.

This question is similar to: Can Strapi be deployed through Amazon Lightsail?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@Anuga Fixed the question. Can you help me with that now?

Whats your output, if you in the server terminal, execute : curl localhost:1337 ? and what does your .env file contain? (remove tokens and keys)
